# Is it necessary to use HTTP based client/server communication for an app development?

Tags: android, servlets

I want to make an app on Android using MySQL.

I'm new here, so I first see many other's app design. I find one thing is that if they have to use database, they often use RESTful design, defining some API for HTTP protocol for client/server side communication. And then, there're lots of things to do, like: mapping resources into url, sending/recieving doGet, doPost,.. requests.

But I don't understand. This is an app develop, not a web develop. Why do they have to make an app so much like a web? If I don't want to use phoneGap, HTML5, .. that kind of HTML-based develop, I want to write a native app. And I still want to seperate client and server end in my code, my server side could communicate with MySQL, and my client side display it to user, and they're all written in java. Since they're all java, so I got a native idea:

"why don't I call my server side code directly from my client end?"

Since it's all run on an app, there's no necessarity to map it into a url for user to access. But as I observed, most of people don't do this. So I want to know why they donnot make their app the way I think? Is it for security concerning? Or to reduce debug difficulty? Or for later expansion to other platform like iOS?

I want to know why they choose HTTP based client/server communication.

Comment: HTTP is more secure. If you use MySQL directly, an attacker can easily determine how to access your database and then do with it what they wish. By including a web app in the middle, you can filter permissible actions to keep the database safe and valid.

Comment: If you choose SQLite you can have your database locally and not do any http calls. Android I believe has no native support for MySQL, thus http as a common transport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not just about security, because in either way you'd be setting an external `Socket` to the destination, but also because there's no native way to communicate between you app and `MySQL`. The most common approach in this way is using a web-service, where you'd implement a HTTP server with some code in your favourite language (PHP, Python...) that would process your requests made by your clients and process them accordingly. This third-party script would communicate with the database.

If you finally choose this approach and you're concerned about security, I'd choose some asymmetric encryption algorithm as `TLS`, where you could encrypt your messages with the public key and decrypt them in the server side with the private key.

You can share the public key with no concerns, you can simply embed in your code, but you could also put it in your web-server and make your clients download it each time they connect. This way, if some day you change it (because of a Heartbleed situation, for instance), they'll always have the current public key; otherwise, you'd need to update your app if you hardcode the public key in your code.

Some useful links:

- [Android Encryption with the Android Cryptography API](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/encrypting-with-android-cryptography-api.html)
- [Create SSL-Socket over SSL-Socket with Client Authentication](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/encrypting-with-android-cryptography-api.html)
- [How dangerous might be publishing a public key?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54353/how-dangerous-might-be-publishing-a-public-key)

Comment: thank you, so it's for security concerning. 

I'm asking this because I've see some people successfully using jdbc directly to get MySQL on Android. And there's a tutorial to do so:  http://blog.csdn.net/conowen/article/details/7435231 

But it's also unrecommended to do this if the database is frequently access. So I'll choose web-service way, and your information is very helpful.